# rvalue ссылки и переменные

Tags: c++

Можно использовать rvalue ссылки вместо переменных, если отбросить вопрос эффективности определения? Как видно из кода ниже разница в двух ассемблерных командах.

```
   int&& r = 1;
00CB6582  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],1  
00CB6589  lea         eax,[ebp-18h]  
00CB658C  mov         dword ptr [r],eax  
    int* p = &r;
00CB658F  mov         eax,dword ptr [r]  
00CB6592  mov         dword ptr [p],eax  

    ++r;
00CB6595  mov         eax,dword ptr [r]  
00CB6598  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
00CB659A  add         ecx,1  
00CB659D  mov         edx,dword ptr [r]  
00CB65A0  mov         dword ptr [edx],ecx  

    int i = 2;
00CB65A2  mov         dword ptr [i],2  
    int* p2 = &i;
00CB65A9  lea         eax,[i]  
00CB65AC  mov         dword ptr [p2],eax  

    ++*p2;
00CB65AF  mov         eax,dword ptr [p2]  
00CB65B2  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
00CB65B4  add         ecx,1  
00CB65B7  mov         edx,dword ptr [p2]  
00CB65BA  mov         dword ptr [edx],ecx
```

Comment: На каком уровне оптимизации компилировался этот код?

Comment: @AnT ни на каком, этот код из дебагера VS, а что переменный лучше оптимизируются чем ссылки?

Comment: `rvalue` ссылки тоже являются переменными. `int&& r = 1;` создает две переменных вместо одной.

Comment: Утверждения типа "разница в двух ассемблерных командах" не имеют никакого смысла для отладочной версии кода.

Comment: Я отказался от **rvalue** переменных, так как доступ к этой переменной происходит косвенно. Переменная в стеке `int&&` указывает на **rvalue** объект типа **int** (тоже в стеке). А если просто переменную оставить как **int** , то запрос значения будет только один.

Comment: Оптимизировать низкий уровень (не затрагивая алгоритм) можно 1) некоторыми ключевыми словами ( register, auto так как регистров процессора не много, то перестановкой слова разным переменным)   2) ассемблерными вставками. Думаю что & и * - чисто "косметическая" оптимизация (что б код красиво или привычно выглядел).

Comment: register уже просто пустышка, ничего оно не оптимизирует. Если нужна оптимизация, то либо оптимальнее алгоритмы, либо проще код, что  бы не мешать компилятору.